# probability of a 50/50 event occurring 15/20 times divided by the probability of a 75/25 event occurring 15/20 times

Tags: statistics, bayesian, binomial-distribution

The material I am working with:

http://personal.vu.nl/a.f.de.vos/primer/primer.pdf

Article describes probability of a 50/50 event occurring 15/20 times divided by the probability of a 75/25 event occurring 15/20 times as being equal to 1/13.7% or 7.2992%

I am getting 7.3077%

Is this a rounding issue or am I offtrack? You can see my attempt at calculating the binomial distribution below

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: better or worse? I am open to suggestion for title, having explored this stuff much, don't have concepts or lingo down

Comment: It's a little better, yeah. It's hard for me to suggest a title because the question isn't very clear.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: tried to clarify question/title & ty for link. hopefully someone is able to make sense of my title and help me figure this out.

Comment: That's much better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability that an event with probability $p$ will occur exactly $15$ times out of $20$ is $${20\choose15}p^{15}(1-p)^5$$
Therefore, the quotient you seek is $${.5^{20}\over .75^{15}.25^5}\approx.073077$$ and I think you are correct.

Comment: Thank you. Just wanted to double check that I am on right track. IMO the fractions are more confusing than decimals, wish they would just use decimals.